# What is a cheek press event?

Tags: java, android, methods, flags, popupwindow

In the Android docs for a `PopupWindow`, the method `setIgnoreCheekPress()` is mentioned. It says that this method "Sets the flag on popup to ignore cheek press event; by default this flag is set to false which means the pop wont ignore cheek press dispatch events."

Quite simply, what is a `cheek press dispatch event`?

Comment: Pretty much exactly what it sounds like. :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's the event dispatched when your cheek presses against the phone.

Events have a size, the size is compared against a threshold to determine if it's a "cheek", e.g., if the size is bigger than some "it's a finger" threshold. This allows phones to not react when someone has the phone up to their face and their cheek is pressing on the screen.

---

*Clarification from comment.* The phone does not know you've specifically pressed with your cheek. It assumes you're not rubbing up on it with other large (compared to a finger) body parts. Ew.

Comment: Whoa, cool. How does android know when you're specifically pressing with your cheek?

Comment: Works fine for me with any of my 4 cheeks ;)

Comment: @Simon I shudder to imagine the API integration testing.

Answer (score 6):

Detects when you put your face to the phone, for example to turn off the screen during a phone call.